# Is it possible to clear force:inputField?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller

I have a `force:inputField` field on my lightning component acting as a lookup. It is working fine:

```
<force:inputField aura:id="segmentid" value="{!v.campaign.Survey__c}"/>
<ui:button press="{!c.selectSurvey}">Add Survey</ui:button>
```

The controller looks up the record information, displays it on the page, and then the callback should clear the `force:inputField` so the user can add another record. This is what I have tried:

```
var forceChange = cmp.get("v.campaign");
forceChange.Survey__c = ""  ;
cmp.set("v.campaign", forceChange);
```

I have also tried clearing/setting the `v.value` and `v.text` of the object but that doesnt seem to work:

```
cmp.find("segmentid").set("v.value", "");
cmp.find("segmentid").set("v.text", "");
```

Out of desperation I tried to force a refresh on both methods to no effect:

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

I'm out of ideas but I need this to work.

Comment: what is the type of your `campaign` attribute?

Comment: @ItaiShmida it's a custom sobject:  `<aura:attribute name="campaign" type="Proof_Campaign__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Proof_Campaign__c' }" access="public"/>`

Comment: Try cmp.set ("v.campaign", "");

Comment: @ItaiShmida yeah that doesnt work either :(

Comment: As a workaround what if you simply set the value of `v.campaign.Survey__c` to null? Since it is bound to it then it should clear the value from the input as well.

Comment: @Eric that's what I thought as well. but I've tried setting `v.campaign.Survey__c` to `null` and to `""`.  Neither seem to work.

Comment: I found similar behavior using lightning rich text. I abandoned it when I found it did not even bind the value as expected either. Might need to just drop it and use lightning input for now...Hopefully someone will have a workaround but looks like you tried the supported ways to do it.

Comment: It would be to your benefit if you posted the complete code for your component, including the controller and any helper methods.  Also, if you've not tried this approach, you may want to try using unbound expressions in your code (available SP17).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically it should be possible to clear values on `force:inputField`. But in your specific case it seems not to work as expected. `force:inputField` is a smart field component operating on different field types differently. For bound plain text fields the reset works while for lookups attribute updates are not rendered correctly.

**Known Weakpoints**

There are lots of posts here and elsewhere indicating that `force:inputField` has several flaws. I personally tried it about two years ago an then gave up on it. In the meantime however it looks improved a bit. But I would definitely suggest to use it carefully.

The way you are using `cmp.get()` and `set()` looks correct. But my experience with Lightning is: even small typos might end up to a ignored-behaviour with no errors so debugging is a challenge.

Also the [Lightning Component Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm) shows two planned components `lightning:inputField` and `lightning:lookup`. Now my interpretations of that is, that Salesforce is aware of the limitations of the current `force:inputField` and is working on a successor.

**Issue Isolation**

I would start to isolate the issue and extract it out of your given scenario into a new puristic test compo using only stanard objects, like Contact with the AccountId lookup. Then you'll have short code to post here in full length (as @crmprogdev suggested) and at the same time ruled out a bunch of possible side effects.

I've tried this already, but the results aren't looking very promising (see below). Therefore I would recommend to search for solutions without `force:inputField`.

**Alternatives**

Instead of `force:inputField` you could try to:

- write you own custom lookup component, or look at existing stuff:
- http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/07/custom-lookup-lightning-component/
- https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html
- http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/lookup-component-in-salesforce-lightning/

I haven't tested the these examples yet.

**My attempts using force:inputField**

I've played around a bit using that markup

```
<aura:component controller="elfUHForceInputFields" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">       
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="Contact" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }" />
    <force:inputField value="{!v.Contact.FirstName}" />
    <force:inputField value="{!v.Contact.Salutation}" />
    <force:inputField value="{!v.Contact.AccountId}" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="do it" onclick="{! c.onClick }" />         
</aura:component>
```

With this Apex invoked in an init-handler and the result assigned to v.Contact

```
public class elfUHForceInputFields {
    @AuraEnabled public static Contact load(String id) {
        return Database.query( xs.soql('select *, Account.* from Contact where Id= :id') );
    }
}
```

My observations are

- `force:inputField` bound to text fields like FirstName get populated
- `force:inputField` bound to Salutation (picklist) gets populated
- `ui:input` bound to Account.Name gets populated
- `force:inputField` **bound to AccountId (lookup) doesn't get populated**

But you can use the UI to pick an Account:

- Rendering looks ok.
- attribute v.Contact.AccountId gets updated correctly!

Now back to you scenario in an onclick-handler after manually populating the Account lookup:

- cmp.set('v.Contact.FirstName','test') updates the attribute and the UI
- cmp.set('v.Contact.AccountId',null)  updates the attribute **but doesn't update the UI**
- same goes for setting the entire Contact.AccountId to null ==> no UI update

This inconsistent behavior looks like a bug and verifies your observation.

My idea to work around it was to dynamically create the `force:inputField` using `$A.createComponent()` in a handler and then destroy and recreate the inputField when you need to clear it.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

I've tried this

```
   $A.createComponent(
        "force:inputField",
        {
            "value"  : cmp.getReference("v.Contact.FirstName"),
        },
        function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newCmp);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );
```

Unfortunately this only brings up:

> Error: An internal server error has occurred Error ID:
>   1690735821-95785 (-1543061012)

**Conclusion**

I looks like you have to implement your own lookup compo to get what you need. Possibly it's worth to test the W18 update for improvements.

Comment: Great post.  I ended up placing the force:inputField in a component by itself and dynamically creating/refreshing it from a container. Even though this worked I found other weirdness with it.  For example force:inputField will not refresh/render if its nested in a <div>.

Answer (score 2):

After toying with force:inputField a bit, I found the following code to clear it's value.

```
// Clear binded value
var contractLine = component.get('v.contractLine');
contractLine.Product__c = null;
contractLine.Product__r = {'sobjectType': 'Product2'};
component.set('v.contractLine', contractLine);    

// Clear product lookup
var productLookup = component.find('Product').get('v.body')[0];
productLookup.updateValues();
```